# blender api - get current location and rotation of camera tracking an object

Tags: python, objects, camera, tracking

I have a camera with an object constraint to track an empty plain axes. I want to get the camera's current rotation, since when the axes move, or when the camera changes location, the camera rotates in order to track the axes.

however, when I read the value using  C.scene.camera.rotation_euler, the values never change, even though the camera clearly has rotated in order to follow the axes.

```
>>> C.scene.camera.rotation_euler
Euler((-0.2408553957939148, -0.0, 0.0), 'XYZ')
```

How do I get the correct values of the camera rotation?
[image: tracking axes, original position]

[image: axes move, camera rotation values are unchanged]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the matrices**

Use the cameras matrices to get the visual transform.  For global transform use `ob.matrix_world`

```
>>> C.scene.camera.matrix_world.to_euler()
Euler((1.1093189716339111, -0.0, 0.8149281740188599), 'XYZ')

>>> C.scene.camera.matrix_local.to_euler()
Euler((1.1093189716339111, -0.0, 0.8149281740188599), 'XYZ')
```

The matrix can be decomposed to location, rotation and scale. The quaternion rotation can be converted to Euler if need be.

```
>>> loc, rot, scale = C.scene.camera.matrix_world.decompose()
>>> rot
Quaternion((0.7804827094078064, 0.483536034822464, 0.20870360732078552, 0.33687159419059753))

>>> rot.to_euler()
Euler((1.1093189716339111, 4.011331711240018e-09, 0.8149281740188599), 'XYZ')
```